# Python quits unexpectedly. PyQt5 QProgressBar is not showing and ValueError: unknown url type

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am learning python and I am doing a tutorial on Desktop Applications but when running the file Python quits unexpectedly and the PyQt5 QProgressBar is not setting the value or updating from the report function. I am also getting a `ValueError`:

```
unknown url type error.raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url) ValueError: unknown url type:
```

Please assist. I have included the code below.

[image]

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import urllib
import urllib.request

import sys

class Downloader(QDialog):

def __init__(self):
#vertical box layout
QDialog.__init__(self)

layout = QVBoxLayout()


self.url = QLineEdit()
self.save_location = QLineEdit()
# creating progress bar
self.progress = QProgressBar(self)
download = QPushButton("Download")

#Placeholder Text
self.url.setPlaceholderText("URL")
self.save_location.setPlaceholderText("File Save Location")

#Progress Bar
self.progress.setMinimum(0)
self.progress.setValue(0)
#self.progress.setProperty("value", 0)
#self.progress.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter) #Centers horizontally
# setting alignment to centre
self.progress.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)


#Add Widget
layout.addWidget(self.url)
layout.addWidget(self.save_location)
layout.addWidget(self.progress)
layout.addWidget(download)

self.setLayout(layout)
self.show()

#setting the title
self.setWindowTitle("PyDownloader")
self.setFocus()

download.clicked.connect(self.download)


#Event Handler
#Method responsible for downloading the file
def download(self):
#sets the url to whatever text the user has typed in
url = self.url.text()
save_location = self.save_location.text()
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,save_location,self.report)

#url retrieve method - to download the file
def report(self, blocknum, blocksize ,totalsize):
readsofar = blocknum * blocksize
if totalsize > 0:
percent = readsofar * 100 / totalsize
self.progress.setValue(int(percent))

# create pyqt5 app
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
# create the instance of our Downloader
d1 = Downloader()
#app.exec_()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: please improve your indentation, in python is very important

Comment: The problem is simple: the url you put in the QLineEdit is invalid, for example an empty string is an invalid url